# Unable to fix a JS generated CSS height

Tags: javascript, css, height

I am having an issue with a [web application](http://ictlabs.elte.hu/calendar) I am currently working with.

The javascript generated html elements get a js generated css height attribute, which is wrong, and it would be nice to fix this height.

When clicking on en event placed under a day (for example sample event) a JS shows up a windows with the event's details. This easedIn windows get a JS generated height: `352px` for example.

Could you please help me out exactly which function in the JS generates this height, and how to modify it to hide all the calendar behind the easedIn window? (Alse it would be nice to darker the content behind the eased windows, but this is not the main aim)

I am trying to solve this issue for days now, and really have no more ideas.

Comment: I guess it could be in eventer-1.0.min.js file, but it is minified and it is quite hard to define what does what. However, there is this piece of code that could change the height of the target element:  `$('li.date-box-row-'+rowID).each(function(index,element){$(this).attr('data-date-box-height',totalHeight)});`

Comment: any ideas how to change that? i am quite new to JS functions...

Comment: i have replaced the JS with no min version:

http://ictlabs.elte.hu/calendar/js/eventer.js

Comment: I cannot fix this without having the whole code and making some test (with console.log etc...), but the line that is setting the height is `$($targetDateBox).animate({
width: calendarWidth,       height: calendarHeight + self.dateBoxTopOffset,
left: 0,         top: -self.dateBoxTopOffset },`. So you should try to see how is calculated `calendarHeight`, which is itself calculated from `#month-dates-container`, which is itself calculated from `dateBoxHeight`. To sum up: that's a mess ^^